# Cannot use resources in AAR pack in Android Library module:cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-library, aar, cannot-find-symbol

the project structure is:

```
project
--app
--library_module1
--library_module2
```

and i need to use AAR files in library_module1.

i put aars in `library_module2` and added them using `artifacts.add()` in build.gradle, then
using them in `library_module1`

the java classes can be used correctly, but the resources like `R.id.blabla` cannot, the IDE tells me `canot resolve symbols`, and build failed here too.

I checked the AAR files, find that there is `R.txt`s in them.But i cannot use them.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?